# deploy java war file to IBM web sphere portal

Tags: java, websphere, war, websphere-7, websphere-portal

I have java war file and i want deploy into IBM web sphere portal.

Kindly tell me steps to deploy java war file

Many Thanks

Comment: Folks please reply me.................

Answer (score 1):

Portal runs on top of a WAS instance - you can just use the WAS Admin console to install the WAR as you would on any standard WebSphere environment. The link to access your Admin Console is dependent on the host, the port that admin console is bound to and the version of WAS you are running - so I can't tell you what it is. On WAS7 + Portal it is typically something like:

```
https://myhost:10032/ibm/console/
```

Comment: You can find the port number of the server in <WebSphere_Install_Rooot>/wp_profile/config/cells/<CELL_NAME>/nodes/<NODE_NAME>/serverindex.xml. This has the list of server instances and the Port number of various for WAS and Portal Console (both secured and unsecured)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Malcolm Smith in previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249364/762913, easiest way is to use the admin console (locally or on the deployment manager, if you have a network deployment).

One word of caution though - the "standard" license for Websphere Portal does **not** allow you to deploy non-portal/portlet applications. You have a license to run Websphere **Portal**, not a license for the Websphere Application Server (WAS) on itself. So if you are considering deploying a standalone application (web application, web service, whatever) onto a Websphere Portal installation, I would check your license carefully so that you actually have a license for WAS as well as Portal. Otherwise, if IBM audits your company and finds out, they may back-charge you for WAS licenses plus penalty, which is not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a WAR file with a portlet(s)?

Try this link: 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Export_the_WAR_file_and_install_the_portlet_wp7 - step 2 onwards.

Comment: No Sir...that is purely java war file and i want to deploy into web sphere portal..please help me in this..Thanks

Comment: Hello folks can you please respond

Comment: Technically you should be still able to deploy non-portlet JEE applications on WPS in the same way as you would on WAS *(http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/welc6topdeveloping.html). However, I'd also check WPS license as there might be some limitations.