# URL to access Web App deployed as a WAR file on Websphere Portal Server

Tags: websphere-portal

We have deployed a simple Web App containing JSPs and Servlets as a .war file to the IBM Websphere Portal Server. However we are not able to figure out the URL to use to access or view the Web App. Can we access the Web app using an independent web app or do we need to create a Portal page for the same.

Any information or help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way. You can access it directly or as a portlet. When you deploy the .war file to the WAS Console, you have to set a context root. The context root will be the root of the URI for accessing your Web App.
Depending on what type of app it is and how you plan to use it, you may need to use the XMLAccess interface to register the App with portal.
I could point you to the relevant documentation if you could provide the Portal version you are using.

Here are some resources for Portal v7:
[deploy java war file to IBM web sphere portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225680/deploy-java-war-file-to-ibm-web-sphere-portal)

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+7+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Export_the_WAR_file_and_install_the_portlet_wp7&content=pdcontent